# Change default new line to <p> tag tinymce rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using tinymce and save my content to db. What happened is when i press enter in the tinymce it is inserting `<br>` tag.

so i changed something in the tinymce config to:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  force_br_newlines : false,
  force_p_newlines : true,
  ...
}
```

This severed my purpose. But when i paste the content from word. Its still inserts `<br>`.

Is there any work around for this.

Thanks in advance.

Note: My tinymce version is 3.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You may modify pasted content as you like using the [paste_preprocess - Tinymce config parameter](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:paste_preprocess).

```
tinymce.init({
    paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
        console.log(args.content);

        // your modifications here

        // example
        args.content = args.content.replace(/<br>/, '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey! Do you know a way to do this with regular text?. (To change the styles of the new added lines and args.content.replace(/<p>/, '<p style="">') for example.

Thanks!